# ¿Por qué no obtengo el valor de un input con getElementById(id)?

Tags: javascript, html

No sé porque no funciona, ya que no estoy obteniendo el valor que contiene el input con la línea:

```js
var peso= document.getElementById(peso);
```

Código:

```js
function peso()
{
    var dolar= 20;
    var peso= document.getElementById(peso);
    var res= peso*dolar;
    alert(peso + "pesos son... " + res + " dólares");
}

function dolar()
{
    var peso= .20;
    var dolar=document.getElementById(dolar);
    var res2= dolar*peso;
    alert(dolar + "dólares son... " + res2 + " pesos");
}
```

```html
<p>
  <input name="peso" type="text" id="peso" size="8" maxlength="10"/>
  <input name="dolar" type="button" onclick="peso()" value="Convertir a dólares"/>
</p>

<input name="dolar2" type="text" id="dolar" size="8" maxlength="10"/>
<input name="peso2" type="button" onclick="dolar()" value="Convertir a pesos mexicanos"/>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dos posibles errores en su código.

1. El **id** seleccionado del `document` , mediante [**getElementById('id')**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) **debe ir entre comillas (simples o dobles).**
2. Para acceder al valor del `input` ,se debería acceder al valor de la propiedad **value**.

   ```
   /* Cambiar */
   var peso= document.getElementById(peso);
   /* Por */
   var peso= document.getElementById("peso").value;
   /* Cambiar */
   var dolar=document.getElementById(dolar);
   /* Por */
   var dolar=document.getElementById("dolar").value;
   ```